# Image assets appearing at wrong resolution on iPad Pro

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `tabbar` controller. I have added `tabbar` item images to image Assets as 1x, 2x and 3x respectively.

When I run the app with iPhone and iPad, it is normal. The 2x image size is `60*60` and `tabbarItem`. Image shows `60*60` for iPad. But when it comes to the iPad Pro, it is showing 30*30. Could any one explain why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: how did u found its 30*30 or 60*60 in manually or progrmatically

Comment: programatically

Comment: see this once the Custom Icon Sizes  https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/